# How can I send an email notification to user on first time log in to salesforce?

Tags: email-alert, loginflow

We want to send email notification to user on first time login to Salesforce. Has any one tried it?

I did it using a trigger but I am not able to get it done using Workflow. I can't compare `LastLogin` with the old value in Workflow as it is not available in formula based rule.

Salesforce doesn't fire any trigger/Workflow/Process on `LastLogin` date update.

I ended up using trigger to send the email.

Is there any documentation that says last login date update wont fire triggers?

Comment: Your question as written seems rather vague and very broad. The comments you've written in response to an answer below are some of the details that would have been very helpful to include in your initial post and would likely have provided you with a more useful answer. I suggest you visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to send it based upon the first time they ever log in could you have a workflow/trigger/process that fires off of LastLoginDate.  When they have never logged in that value is blank.

Comment: I did it using trigger but I am not able to get it done using WF. I can't compare  lastlogin with the old value in WF as it is not available in formula based rule.

Comment: Yeah that strange you can use it for Criteria but is not there when trying to make a formula.  You can use it in PB so you might try that if you dont want to use Apex.